# The average age of 30 boys in a class is 16, including the teacher it is 17. What is the teacher's age?

Tags: average, word-problem

The average age of $30$ boys in a class is $16$. If the teachers is included the average increases by $1$. What is the teacher's age?

**Options:**

1. $37$ yrs
2. $30$ yrs
3. $47$ yrs
4. $57$ yrs
5. None of these

As I tried to solve my answer is $47$ 
but my friend said that it is wrong
am i making any silly mistake.

Actually what I did:
First of all I set sum of age of all students equal to $S$ and noted 
$S/30=16$. Thus $S=480$.
Then denoting teacher's age by $x$ I have
$(480+x)/(30+1)=(16+1)$ whence $x=47$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: $31\times17-30\times16$

Comment: thanks @5xum for your suggestion...i am really sorry because i am a newbee to this forum....please review and let me know if i did something wrong

Comment: Your solution is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve for $\;x=$ the teacher's age:

$$\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_{30}+x}{31}=\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_{30}}{30}+1$$

With the given data, the above is much easier than it may look at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N_a$ be the sum of all students age and $N_t$ be the teachers age,

Since there are 30 students, we can write it as $\frac{N_a}{30}=16$, so it gives $N_a=480$, now according to the aforementioned question $\frac{N_a+N_t}{30+1}=17\rightarrow480+N_t=527$, so the teacher's age is $47$.

Comment: This is a very low quality question, so it should not be answered. Especialliy not in such detail.